# template specialization/initializations and namespaces?

Tags: c++, template-specialization, static-initialization, fully-qualified-naming

What are C++'s rules regarding template specialization and namespace qualification? I had some code that boiled down to the equivalent of the following, and it made me realize that I don't understand C++'s rules regarding template specialization initializations. It seems weird to me firstly that the specializations of `g::F<>` are even allowed inside `h`, but given that, I don't know why things act the way they do.

```
namespace g {

  struct N {
    N(char c):c_(c){}
    char c_;
  };

  template <typename V>
  struct F {
    static N n_s; // <-- want to initialize these for specializations
  };

  namespace h {
    struct X { static constexpr char k{'x'}; };

    template <> N F<char>::n_s{h::X::k};  // OK
    template <> N F<int>::n_s{X::k};      // fails on "‘X’ not declared"
  }
} // namespace g

// Seems weirdest to me. N and F need full qualifications but X doesn't.
template <> g::N g::F<float>::n_s{h::X::k}; // OK also!
```

The last instantiation/initialization, where the template static member initializer infers the `g` namespace, makes it seem as though the template acts as though the initializer acts as though it were located in the same spot in code as the template definition itself.

What is the rule of the specification that dictates this behavior? (Note that this was tested on gcc 4.8.1, and looks thus far a bit like a bug...)

Answer (score 2):

The key confusion here is not about specialization, but about qualification. Let's look at the last specialization (in the global namespace) to illustrate this:

```
template <> g::N g::F<float>::n_s{h::X::k};
```

As the line starts, you're in the global namespace. Thus, `g::N` is necessarily qualified, as is `g::F<float>`.

However, the moment you're past the thing you specialize (i.e. after `n_s`), you're now in the scope of the thing you're specializing, i.e. inside `g::F`. All further lookup is done from within this scope, so `x` must be qualified as `h::X`.

That said, while it's allowed to specialize things in a namespace that encloses the original namespace, specializing within a nested namespace (`h` in your case) looks weird to me, but the standard is mildly ambiguous here, as it says in 14.7.3/2: "An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template."

The global namespace encloses `F`, so that's fine, as is `g`. `h` does not enclose `F`, but then, `h` is within `g`, so the specialization is within `g` too, which technically makes this fine. However, by this reasoning, you can specialize a template absolutely everywhere, because you're always in inside the global namespace, which encloses everything. So I'm pretty sure GCC's behavior here is too permissive, and a bug. You should try this with other compilers too and then file a bug, or possibly a defect report against the standard.

Comment: Thanks, this is along the lines of what I suspected, but I couldn't find a direct contradiction in reading the spec. I was attempting to alias a template like F into a nested namespace like h when I distilled it down to the plainest equivalent case/behavior above.

Answer (score -1):

In:

```
template <> N F<int>::n_s{X::k};      // fails on "‘X’ not declared"
```

It fails because the namespace associated with `F<int>::n_s` is  `g`, whereas `X` is declared in `g::h`. This is why you need to spell it out like `h::F<int>::n_s`.

Comment: huh? do you mean spell it out like g::F<int>::n_s? I can plainly see that it has to be qualified as though from namespace g wherever it is used, but I don't see why the F<char>::n_s initialization is allowed in h or why the F<float>::n_s{h::X::k} initialization is allowed outside of g without the additional g:: qualifier...